# D3JS How to Adapt Scatterplot to Show "semi-continuous" X-Axis Data

Tags: javascript, d3.js, graph, charts

This question is kind of conceptual, so if this isn't the right place for this, I apologize.

I have an existing scatterplot that has continuous Y-axis data and used to have continuous X-axis data. My X-axis data has now changed to semi-continuous, it's a set series of number (cost values), like `[200, 450, 600, 900, 1400]`. There are about 250 'points' on the scatter-plot, but now it seems strange because the X values are not continuous, and they create vertical columns of points.

Without creating an entirely new graph, is there something I can add or do to these data points to better represent them? I was thinking something along the lines of a box-whisker, but a box-whisker wouldn't work for these values.

**Edit** Question Clarification:

Is there a type of chart or adjustment that I can make to this chart to better display these values as unique, interesting points of data?

[image]

Comment: What do you want to show?

Comment: I want the user to better be able to distinguish between the points and their values. The user is looking for values that are low-cost/low-year.

Comment: Could you make the points smaller or only show the minimum year for each cost?

Comment: It's a tool for exploring data, data on mouseover, so it needs to have each of the points. I supposed I could reduce the area of the points.

Comment: [fisheye](http://bost.ocks.org/mike/fisheye/)?

Comment: Interesting idea, but [".. unsuitable for visualizations that have quantitative position encodings, such as scatterplots."](http://bost.ocks.org/mike/fisheye/#cartesian).

Comment: @Himmel, look at the cartesian distoriation.

Comment: Guess I would have figured that out if I had read the next paragraph...

Comment: @Mark, do you have or know where to find an example of the cartesian distortion? I can't find even a simple example with how to communicate with the plugin...

Comment: @Himmel, sorry just going through and responding to some comments I missed.  The only example I know is the page I linked.  Are you still struggling with this? I can try and put a minimal sample together.

Comment: I've since gotten it figured out. Thanks for offering, though.